# How to find the first node of the tree in a dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, tree, nodes

i have a big problem , in a function for start to work i need to find the first node in a tree , here an example :

```
              "hi"
            /     \
           /       \
          "ok"     "no"
          /
         /
       "lol"
```

the problem is that i dont know how to take it from a dict , because the input is like this :

```
{ "ok":["lol"] , "no":[] , "hi": ["ok","no"] , "lol" : [] }
```

so in this case "hi" is the first because nobody has "hi" in dict.values() the problem is how to say that and most important the dict has 50'000 nodes so if i check one by one it goes in overtime .

i wrote this :

```
    d = { "ok":["lol"] , "no":[] , "hi": ["ok","no"] , "lol" : [] }
    x = d.values()
    x = str(x)
    for y in d.keys():
        if not y in x :
            first_node = y
            break
```

but the problem is that can be a word like "hello" and a "key" like "hell" so "hell" is in "hellow" but is not "hellow" :(

Comment: hello not hellow sorry

Comment: You can (and should) edit your question instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to do it using [`set.difference`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference).

```
from itertools import chain

d = { "ok":["lol"] , "no":[] , "hi": ["ok","no"] , "lol" : [] }
roots = set(d).difference(chain.from_iterable(d.values()))
```

gives us

```
{'hi'}
```

Comment: but if i have this list : {'bellissimanon': ['cio', 'cia'], 'cio': [], 'belissima': ['belissimanon'], 'cia': []}  he gives back {'belissima', 'bellissimanon'} , but it should be only "bellissima"

Comment: @AliToccacieli Is it intentional that you have two different spellings of `belissimanon` there?

Comment: yeah, its a spelling mistake and therefore you have 2 starting nodes

Comment: my error , it works niceee tnx so much because all the exercise was correct only when the first node was not in order the result was different but now is good tnx ^.^ best !!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension:

```
d = { "ok":["lol"] , "no":[] , "hi":["ok","no"] , "lol" : [] }
root = [a for a, b in d.items() if all(a not in d for c, d in d.items())][0]
```

Output:

```
'hi'
```

Comment: same problem as i write up if the dictionary is like that :

        d = {"bellissimanon":["cio","cia"],"cio":[],"belissima["belissimanon"],"cia":[]}


he give us back :
      
          'bellissimanon' if u put [1] "bellissima" that it mean 2 result

Answer (score 0):

You could pick a random node and follow it to the top.
I just wrote something up, im gonna timeit and report results:

```
d = { "ok":["lol"] , "no":[] , "hi": ["ok","no"] , "lol" : []}

node = list(d.keys())[0]
found = False
while not found:
    found = True
    for key, value in d.items():
        if node in value:
            node = key
            found = False

print(node)
```

---

Turns out that my solution performed best in the test environment:

```
**10 nodes**
0.0000020000017 s - my solution
0.0000043555594 s - using set.diffrence by Patrick Haugh
0.0001111112098 s - list comprehension by Ajax1234

**1000 nodes**
0.0007560006720 s - my solution
0.0015977791980 s - using set.diffrence by Patrick Haugh
0.3337478522203 s - list comprehension by Ajax1234

**10000 nodes**
0.0077213401967 s - my solution
0.0138804567826 s - using set.diffrence by Patrick Haugh
35.264710457520 s - list comprehension by Ajax1234
```

Comment: i did it tnx anyways i will try this too and see witch is more faster tnx to every one :D

Comment: Mine is the fastest, but `set.diffrence` finds all roots